# default route parameter react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a question about setting up default route parameters in React-Router v4. My code currently redirects to the Channel Component with a url of '/channel/:channelName', but I want it to automatically redirect to '/channel/general'.

```
<Route path='/channel/:channelName'
    render={props => (
        this.state.user ?
            <Channel {...props} user={this.state.user} /> :
            <Redirect to='/signin' />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no so called `IndexRoute` anymore in `react-router v4`. You don't need to explicitly specify an index page. Rather, you can give a wildcard match at the end of the mappings like this.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew} />
    <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
    <Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
</Switch>
```

Notice that the order matters and that wildcard match should be the last. This syntax also provides a lot more flexibility over `IndexRoute`.